# How to insert the null value into a field of the @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring-mvc

in this small project in spring-boot that I created, through a simple get, passing it the fields "firstname" and "username", I get back a message in json with all the information on that particular User. This is my Request class

```
public class UsersRequest implements Serializable {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

I have this in my controller

```
   public UsersResponse getMyUsers(@RequestBody UsersRequest request) throws IOException {
    //some code
    }
```

I want to be able to pass null as a value in the "firstName" field, only that when I put the null in the firstName, my get completely deletes the firstName field and does it only with the "lastName"

For my request:

```
{
   firstName : "" , //i have a deserializer which converts empty strings to null
   lastName : "Treehard"
}
```

The request that I then see being made is this

```
Request{"lastName":"Trehard"}
```

Is there a way to pass null as a value and make it possible to get both fields without deleting any of them?

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question body. Did you mean to use `@RequestParam`?

Comment: No, I really meant the @requestBody. I didn't know about that question, I'll follow that one

Comment: Please edit to correct that title. Also what do you mean by _my get completely deletes_?

Comment: Excuse me, I wrote quickly. In the sense that when I go to log my request sent, I see that it is not successful because it is as if it deletes a parameter of the get which therefore does not work

Answer (score 0):

If you pass key or not pass key it will work by adding required attribute ,
Try to do this way
@RequestParam(required = false ,value = "key")String key

Comment: They're sending a JSON body. Are you telling them to scrap that idea and instead send query params/form data?

Comment: I misspelled, I meant the RequestBody, I inherited the question